# C# Selenium - headless browser

Tags: c#, selenium, headless-browser

I develop a small app (in C#) which automatize a test on a website with Selenium. Everything is going well. But when I try the same app with "headless" browser the test doesn't work. I have an issue with the code below :

```
var emailTextBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("j_username"));
```

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:49309/session/d4416c4b-e674-468b-8d6e-6a8bfc9bdf1d/element timed out after 60 seconds.'

The same test works with a normal browser but not in headless mode, I try to use Firefox, Chrome, PhantomJS (all in headless) and it doesn't work...

Do you have an idea ?

My whole code is :

'''

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace MacDo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            var options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.AddArguments("-headless");

            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, options);
            driver.Url = "https://www.mcdonalds.fr/";
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            var seConnecter = driver.FindElement(By.Id("seconnecter"));
            seConnecter.Click();

            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

'''

I use Firefox Browser 73.0.1 (32 bits) (-> I use Geckodriver version 0.26.0)

As said before, it works well, but not in headless mode...

Comment: PhantomJS has been deprecated. Use one of the existing web drivers for modern browsers. Each browser vendor has one now.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to initialize the web driver? Can you also include which browser versions and which versions of the web drivers you are using?

Comment: @GregBurghardt You will see my code and browser version below !

Comment: Your headless option needs two hyphens.  options.AddArguments("--headless");

Comment: @AutomatedOrder I already tried with two hyphens, but it doesn't change anything, I have the same issue...

Comment: Which version of GeckoDriver are you using?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I use version 0.26.0

Comment: Please edit your question and add this info. It gets lost in comments too easily.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: @goskan93 unfortunately no...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in past where script did not work in headless and I found out it was due to default resolution. You can try adding

```
options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
```

Worth trying!